# Spring JPA Hibernate OneToOne

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite some time without success.  I am using:

- Spring 3.1.1
- Hibernate 4.0.1.Final
- spring-data-jpa 1.0.2.RELEASE
- MySQL 5 (org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect)

I have two entities, with a OneToOne non-directional association.  There is NOT a foreign key relationship between the tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "UserName"))
public class User {

    // Fields
    private Long userId;
    private Integer status = 0;
    private String password;
    private Long userRoleId;
    private String userName;
    private UserRole userRole;
...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userRoleId")
    public UserRole getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }
}
```

and a another class that I don't want to be subject to cascade delete/anything as its a reference

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserRole")
public class UserRole {

// Fields
private Long userRoleId;
private String userRoleDescriptionShort;
private String userRoleDescription;

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getUserRoleId() {
    return this.userRoleId;
}
}
```

Each table has userRoleId declared as a bigint

I have two repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
public User findByUserName(String userName);
 }

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserRepository extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements IUserRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public User findByUserName(String userName) {
    QUser user = QUser.user;
    User auser = (User) from(user).where(user.userName.eq(userName));
    return auser;
}
```

**and**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface IUserRoleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRole, Long> {

public UserRole findByRoleDescriptionShort(String roleDescriptionShort);

}

@Repository
Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserRoleRepository extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements IUserRoleRepository     {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public UserRole findByRoleDescriptionShort(String roleDescriptionShort) {
    QUserRole userRole = QUserRole.userRole;
    UserRole arole = (UserRole) from(userRole).where(userRole.userRoleDescriptionShort.equalsIgnoreCase("Owner"));
    return arole;
}
```

however, when I build it I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property role found for type class     com.edelweissco.model.people.UserRole
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.<init>(Property.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.<init>(Property.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.create(Property.java:312)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.create(Property.java:326)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.create(Property.java:326)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.create(Property.java:292)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.from(Property.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Property.from(Property.java:232)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:48)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:242)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.buildTree(PartTree.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>  

(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:303)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:157)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:39)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
```

This seems like a pretty simple way to map, but all the examples I have seen are a bi-directional.  Still, I cannot see why this doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the ForeignKey and the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotations. But the error seems to come from one of your DAOs, not from the mapping.

Comment: We can't see it either, because we don't have the source.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question with more source.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but I don't agree with your mapping. You have declared a OneToOne with a JoinColumn specifying that there is a column on User called userRoleId which is a foreign key to a UserRole. Therefore there must be a foreign key.

Also, I don't believe that this is a OneToOne relationship. You've stated that you shouldn't cascade delete a UserRole when you delete a User. It sounds like a UserRole can be associated with any number of Users. Therefore the mapping on User should be a ManyToOne.

OneToOne is usually appropriate when the two tables share the same key i.e. use PrimaryKeyJoinColumn to indicate that they share a primary key. In this case the two entities have different keys.